# Execute root commands through ssh user

Tags: ssh, sudo, su

my goal is to execute commands as root user from another linux host through ssh.

The Problem is: The environment doesnt allow to access the root user directly.

The manual way, which works, is to connect to the unpriviliged user first by ssh-key, then su to the sudo priviliged user and then sudo -i/sudo su to the root account and execute the commands.

One solution, which looks very convinient to me is using [Python with Paramiko](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436470/538614)

My question is if something like this is possible without Python too.
At the end I want to execute a script, which reads the priviliged user password and then executes commands as root user on the remote system.

I thought about something like this:

```
ssh -t user01@host su user02 -c 'sudo -S cat /etc/shadow'
```

If I execute this command directly on the machine it works, but as soon as I try it over ssh, it throughs the error: `su: invalid option -- 'S'`

It seems to me that their is a problem with the combination of ssh -t and sudo -S, but I don't get it.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are going to do, consider using Ansible. Really. Also you can set "PermitRootLogin without-password", deploy a specific key into root's `authorized_keys` and probably make it restricted to only run commands you are expecting to run, to make this secure.

Comment: Just su - directly to root

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: Thanks! The thing is: I didn't wanted to setup ssh-keys for the root user, because its a one time configuration thing I have to do (actually I just have to add a cronjob to the root users crontab, because the script can only be executed by root). But as it seems, there is no way around. I'm thinking about to setup the ssh-key for the root user and delete it after the config of the deployment is done.

Comment: @gapsf: Thats unfortunately not possible, because I don't have the root password

Comment: Then [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html) is certainly the best way to go. You don't need to install anything particular on the managed host (only Python is required, but chances are it is already there). Try it. (Hint: use "become".)

Answer (score 5):

> ... connect to the unpriviliged user first by ssh-key, then su to the sudo priviliged user and then sudo -i/sudo su to the root account and execute the commands.

The whole point of sudo is to directly associate the person logging in with the sudo'd commands they [are allowed to] execute.  Having a "shared" account in the middle *completely undermines* this.

> ... I want to execute a script which reads the priviliged user password and then executes commands as root user on the remote system.

Again, [properly used] sudo *does away* with all this mucking about.
*You* log in, with *your* password, then use sudo to do stuff (again, with *your* password, if its configured that way).  You don't need the password for the "privileged user" account (because there shouldn't be one) and you certainly don't need (or *want*) the password for **root** (because *nobody* should *ever* get their hands on *that* one).

I would suggest that Your System Administrators need a quick slap round the head with the printed and rolled-up **man** pages for sudo.

You should be logging in as yourself, and using sudo directly from your account.
(If they complain about "management overhead", suggest a local group that is allowed to use sudo, of which your account would be a member).

Answer (score 1):

> The Problem is: The environment doesnt allow to access the root user
> directly.

If you have a need for it, allowing root user to ssh in isn't the end of the world.

For OpenSSH in sshd_config this would be `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`  Perhaps with additional restrictions like matching `Address` to the prefixes of only the expected networks.

A major drawback here is the lack of personal accountability to tie a person to an audit trail of what they did. Only give such a private key to the automation, where all of the commands it runs is documented in version control. No person uses it interactively, that is all as themselves.

Note that adding a switch user program has its own challenges to implement correctly. sudo has had multiple vulnerabilities over the years, and also sudoers policy needs to be written correctly.

---

sudo and su in the same command line is a useless anti-pattern that both muddles access logs, and can result in a less secure authentication due to the password.

Passwords are terribly weak authentication factors. A properly secured ssh key that allows direct root login is more secure.

Comment: Hey John! Thanks for your friendly answer :)
Its more because I'm lazy and don't want to add the ssh-key to the root user, because I only need this once to setup a root crontab. But as I considered above, I think I will do that. So my approach now will be adding the ssh-key to the root user, run my config scripts and delete it afterwards again

Answer (score 1):

This is very straightforward:

```
ssh -t target.host sudo crontab -e -u root
```

This will ask for a password for the connected user on the `target.host`, and requires that user to be in `sudoers` (e.g. in the group `wheel` or `sudo` or whatever is set up in you system). "-t" is needed to obtain a tty for `sudo` to be able to ask the password interactively. If you want to not enter any passwords (to make this fully automatic), you need to set up sudo for this command and this user to be passwordless, or use other approaches.

See `man sudoers`.

One of other approaches is connecting directly as `root` using asymmetric crypto authentication. You may further restrict the key installed into root's `authorized_keys` for it to only permit running the required command:

```
command="crontab -e -u root" ssh-rsa ... <the restricted public key follows>
```

and only permit root login using keys:

```
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
```

then just

```
ssh -i restricted_privkey root@target.host
```

See `man sshd_config`, `man ssh`, `man authorized_keys`.

---

Having said all that, the nature of the task and restrictions really call for the use of [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html). It was designed exactly to meet such requirements.

It will connect over ssh, and it doesn't require anything on the target host to operate, except Python of supported version (>=2.6 or >=3.5). Read the linked manual for details. The `become` feature will tell it to become root using `sudo`, or `su`, whichever method you prefer. There is a dedicated [`cron` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/cron_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-cron-module), so you will have a luxury of having a logic "install a crontab job if it isn't installed yet or update if it was installed before".

Comment: totally forgot about the crontab -u option too! So many ways to rome... Thanks Nikita :) And I defenitly will have a look at Ansible its just not possible in this particular case

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this simply a shell quoting problem?

The remote end sees this command:

```
su user02 -c sudo -S cat /etc/shadow
```

and the `su` command doesn't know what the `-S` flag is.

Try this:

```
ssh -t user01@host "su user02 -c 'sudo -S cat /etc/shadow'"
```

---

(Also, I normally use `ssh -n …` (don't expect anything from stdin), in case the command eventually gets run in a situation where that might make a difference.)

Comment: Wow! That soved the problem! Thanks for answering my question so straight forward. I was confused by the error, because su interpreted the -S but now it makes totally sense! Even if its maybe not the way to go due to security reasons, you helped me to understand the main problem. Thanks again :)